# DriverManager.getConnection() with JDBC SQLite hangs on some PCs

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a user who repeatedly has the problem that the call to [`DriverManager.getConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-) often gets stuck but after a while it might work normally.

My code for opening the database connection is:

```
String className = JDBC.class.getName();
Class.forName(className);
String connectionString = JDBC.PREFIX + databaseFilePath;
```

For every other user this works fine, though. I did not find any related topics on this besides [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868433) but it's not exactly the same issue.

I already added the `Class.forName(className)` call [to register the JDBC driver](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) since I thought it might help but it seemingly isn't necessary anymore to open a database connection.

I'm using [the latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc) `sqlite-jdbc-3.28.0.jar` provided by

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.28.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I did not try another database implementation but I tried to set a login timeout using `setLoginTimeout(10)`.