# Java DriverManager.getConnection hangs when called with wrong parameters

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a Java application with multiple concurrent threads. In a particular situation, I find that the call `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection` hangs and waits indefinitely causing the whole system freeze. 
I suspect I have given the URL wrong, where there is no ORACLE server listening to this call, but there is another DB listener which is not returning back to the socket call. That could be the reason of this hang. When I changed the URL to a wrong value, e.g. jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx:21050:DB, where no DB listener (oracle or non-oracle) is running, `getConnection` call comes out with `java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`.

Is there any other API through which I may check at runtime if the URL is having an ORACLE server listener running out there? My problem for this hang is because I have some other DB (non-ORACLE) listener running there and my `getConnection` hangs. Is there any remedy or workaround?
The thread dump shows me the following:

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0@3511" prio=6 tid=0x15 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(SocketDispatcher.java:-1)
      at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
      at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
      - locked <0x459c> (a java.lang.Object)
      at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:144)
      at oracle.net.ns.NIOHeader.readHeaderBuffer(NIOHeader.java:82)
      at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readNIOPacket(NIOPacket.java:252)
      at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:118)
      at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

I found a similar problem discussed as: [Oracle JDBC DriverManager.getConnection() hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868433/oracle-jdbc-drivermanager-getconnection-hangs) But my question is even if I supply some wrong parameters (URL, userid and password), why the call never comes back with a timeout? Can I add a timeout here or exception that I may handle in this call? Please help me out.

Comment: "I suspect I have given the URL wrong", so you don't even know where you're connecting? It's not timing out because you haven't set a connection timeout, but setting a connection timeout is not required when you connect to the correct URL.

Comment: @Kayaman, my s/w helps out users to connect to multiple DB servers as opted, and this is an area I am trying to get a workaround, as my edited qs. Need to set a connection timeout. How?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683949/connection-timeout-for-drivermanager-getconnection

Comment: Well, first you need to find out what your actual problem is. **If** it really warrants a connection timeout (which is highly *unlikely*), then you can consult the driver's documentation on how to set it. As for @user7294900, that question seems to be about how long a `Connection` is valid for, not the (network) connection timeout.

Comment: @Kayaman, my actual problem is trying to connect to a non-oracle server through Oracle's driver (client) and the non-oracle server doesnot return back nor a socket timeout. Perhaps, DriverManager.setLoginTimeout could have been done? or socket timeout?

Comment: So you have different databases at the same port `21050`, and you don't know whether they're Oracle or non-oracle? Then you connect to them with random drivers, hoping that it's the correct one? And you're trying to solve that with timeouts? Are you really sure about this?

Comment: @Kayaman, it's a bug in the software. While choosing the correct DB server, wrong DB server was chosen causing this. I was looking for a programming remedy with a timeout, thats all

Comment: Well, hopefully someone fixes the bug! But of course you're free to set a timeout. It can differ a bit between databases and drivers on how to do it, so search around.